# Logback debug level not working

Tags: java, jsf, logback

I have this logback.xml in my app (Java 6 / Tomcat 7.0.27 / JSF: Mojarra 2.1.13) file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
    <appender name="LB_STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level {%thread} [%logger{40}] : %msg%n</pattern>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="LB_AOUB_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${catalina.base}/logs/lb_aoub.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level {%thread} [%logger] : %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/lb_aoub-%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern> 
            <maxHistory>60<!-- days -->
            </maxHistory>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>2MB</maxFileSize> 
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="br.com.aoub" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="LB_STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="LB_AOUB_FILE" />
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

The errors, warns and infos are working. But the debug level logs in the application have not been written in the console neither been saved in the file.

If I add this:

```
<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="LB_STDOUT" />
</root>
```

The debug messages are written is the console, but I want to set only the `br.com.aoub` logger to debug, not the entire application.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure your application is using this logback.xml and that you don't have any other file in the classpath that might be overriding it? Can you make some changes to the pattern and see if it gets reflected?

Comment: Yes, because the "lb_aoub.log" is been created with the INFO, WARN and ERROR logs.

Comment: I tried to change the pattern as well. The changes are take effect on the log files but the DEBUGs still not work.